# Acoustic model compatibility issue

Tags: java, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am using sphinx4-5prealpha to do text-audio alignment. I use the Acoustic model and dictionary packed with this version. For some reason I want to use the same AM and acoustic model with an old sphinx-4 version but I get:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 13824, Size: 13824
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Pool.get(Pool.java:55)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.createSenonePool(Sphinx3Loader.java:406)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.loadModelFiles(Sphinx3Loader.java:343)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.linguist.acoustic.tiedstate.Sphinx3Loader.load(Sphinx3Loader.java:280)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.AutoCepstrum.newProperties(AutoCepstrum.java:120)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:161)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponentList(PropertySheet.java:422)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.FrontEnd.newProperties(FrontEnd.java:160)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:290)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.SimpleAcousticScorer.newProperties(SimpleAcousticScorer.java:46)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.scorer.ThreadedAcousticScorer.newProperties(ThreadedAcousticScorer.java:130)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:290)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.search.WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.newProperties(WordPruningBreadthFirstSearchManager.java:201)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:290)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.AbstractDecoder.newProperties(AbstractDecoder.java:71)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.decoder.Decoder.newProperties(Decoder.java:37)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getComponent(PropertySheet.java:290)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.recognizer.Recognizer.newProperties(Recognizer.java:90)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.PropertySheet.getOwner(PropertySheet.java:508)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.util.props.ConfigurationManager.lookup(ConfigurationManager.java:161)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:77)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.Context.<init>(Context.java:49)
at edu.cmu.sphinx.api.SpeechAligner.<init>(SpeechAligner.java:41)
```

Where can I find an older french version of AM and dictionary compatible with older sphinx versions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no good old French acoustic model, you have to use new acoustic model and new code. If there are issues with the new code it is easier to fix them instead.